# Graphic representation of the elements in the XML file

Tags: python, json, xml, twitter-bootstrap, graphic

I`ve got an interesting task and I need to know am I on the right path.
Task is: 
Create Front end visualization using the attached XML file. Visualization should be a graphic representation of the elements in the XML file.

Requirements: 
JSON backend service 
Open source javascript library for the frontend 
Suggested Tools 
Python in combination with Tornado backend language 
Twitter Bootstrap

I have made a setup of Tornado and created python file that opens index.html which will display graphic representation of the elements from the XML file. 
My idea is to parse XML to JSON,and than show output graphically.

I`m uncertain about this things: 
1. Am I on the right path, is there a better solution? 
2. Does anyone have experience for graphic representation...Does graphic representation means something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) ? Or does it mean I can show output as a simple element tree???

All ideas and suggestions are welcome!

---

EDIT:
This is my XML file: http://pastebin.com/AJeNctFY

Comment: if you don't know what you want others can't know either. The file isn't attached, if you don't have sufficient privileges please post a link to the file.

Comment: I`ve said I got this as a task and I`ve typed all the info I have. 
Task info declares what needs to be done, an what are requirements. 
I only asked dev community for help `couse I`m not certan is my idea for realisation good, and how visualisation could look like, by your opinion?

I`m still struggling with this, so if anyone can help I`ll really appreciate it.

Btw, post is edited and now contains xml file.

Answer (score 0):

There could be various representation methods to visualize an XML file. You must first decide what you want. For example, showing XMl elements as nodes of a tree sounds good. But what about attributes? what about the node's value?

For example, you might want to show a notification box to show the attributes and their values. Another option is to show each attribute as a child node of the XML element. As an instance of latter, take a look at this [XML Viewer](http://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer).